# Need to add a fade out effect to a hiding box with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a notification div which dissapears after 5 seconds. How to add a fade out effect that the disappearing would be smooth and nice.

My code now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('notification').style.display = 'none';
}, 5000);  
//5secs
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will start counting after document ready. Can be added anywhere you want. As long as its between `<script></script>` tags or in a differne JS file.

```
$(function(){
    $("#notification").delay(5000).fadeOut(2000); // the 2000 is the time the fadeOut will take to disapear.
});
```

jsfidlle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/jGtTP/

Comment: It worked, but still it disappeared quite fast. Can we control the time of disappearance?

Comment: Change the `2000` to any number you want in MS, which is the time the `fadeOut` takes to fade out.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#notification').delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

You'd add this in a `JavaScript` block, this way:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#notification').delay(5000).fadeOut();

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you could try:

```
$("#notification").effect("fade");
```

More reading: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use jQuery, you could use jsTween (have a search for it on google). I use it for animation on sites, and it is really good, and (in some cases) considerably faster than its jQuery fade counterpart.

```
opacityTween = new OpacityTween(document.getElementById('notification'),Tween.strongEaseInOut, 100, 0, 5);
opacityTween.start()
```

that will fade out the object over 5 seconds

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#notification').attr('style', 'display: none;');
}), 5000);
```